# Not able to insert data into a 2nd table with a db manipulator

Tags: android, sqlite

Im a beginner in Android and this datamanipulator allows me to insert data into the 1st table ("People"), however i can not make it work to add data into the 2nd table ("appointments") using a 2nd method, a 2nd string "insert2". However the data is inserted into the 1st table and not the 2nd table. Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong? Thx in advance!

```
package com.example.citas.medicas;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DataManipulator
{
private static final  String DATABASE_NAME = "mydatabase.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
static final String TABLE_NAME = "Personas";
static final String TABLE_NAME2 = "Citas";
private static Context context;
private static Context context2;
static SQLiteDatabase db;
private SQLiteStatement insertStmt;
private static final String INSERT = "insert into " + TABLE_NAME + " (nombre,cedula,fechanacimiento,telefonocasa,telefonomovil,tipo) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
private static final String INSERT2 = "insert into " + TABLE_NAME2 + " (nombrepaciente,fechacita,horacita,nombredoctor) values (?,?,?,?)";

public DataManipulator(Context context) {
    DataManipulator.context = context;
    OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(DataManipulator.context);
    DataManipulator.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    this.insertStmt = DataManipulator.db.compileStatement(INSERT);
}

public  void DataManipulator(Context context2) {
    DataManipulator.context2 = context2;
    OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(DataManipulator.context2);
    DataManipulator.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    this.insertStmt = DataManipulator.db.compileStatement(INSERT2);
}

public long insert(String nombre,String cedula,String fechanacimiento,String telefonocasa,String telefonomovil,String tipo) {
    this.insertStmt.bindString(1, nombre);
    this.insertStmt.bindString(2, cedula);
    this.insertStmt.bindString(3, fechanacimiento);
    this.insertStmt.bindString(4, telefonocasa);
    this.insertStmt.bindString(5, telefonomovil);
    this.insertStmt.bindString(6, tipo);
    return this.insertStmt.executeInsert();      
}

public long insert2(String nombrepaciente,String fechacita,String horacita,String nombredoctor) {
    this.insertStmt.bindString(1, nombrepaciente);
    this.insertStmt.bindString(2, fechacita);
    this.insertStmt.bindString(3, horacita);
    this.insertStmt.bindString(4, nombredoctor);
    //this.insertStmt.bindString(5, telefonomovil);
    //this.insertStmt.bindString(6, tipo);
    return this.insertStmt.executeInsert();
}

public void deleteAll() {
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
}

public void delete(int rowId) {
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null); 
}

private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    OpenHelper(Context context) {
         super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
         db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, nombre TEXT, cedula TEXT, fechanacimiento TEXT, telefonocasa TEXT, telefonomovil TEXT, tipo TEXT)");
         //B) FINAL NO QUITAR
         db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME2 + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, nombrepaciente TEXT, fechacita TEXT, horacita TEXT, nombredoctor TEXT)");
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
    {
         db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
         onCreate(db);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have two methods that take identical parameters:

```
public DataManipulator(Context context) {
    DataManipulator.context = context;
    OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(DataManipulator.context);
    DataManipulator.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    this.insertStmt = DataManipulator.db.compileStatement(INSERT);
}

public  void DataManipulator(Context context2) {
    DataManipulator.context2 = context2;
    OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(DataManipulator.context2);
    DataManipulator.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    this.insertStmt = DataManipulator.db.compileStatement(INSERT2);
}
```

Try passing a flag instead:

```
public DataManipulator(Context context, boolean first) {
    DataManipulator.context = context;
    OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(DataManipulator.context);
    DataManipulator.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    if(first)
        this.insertStmt = DataManipulator.db.compileStatement(INSERT);
    else
        this.insertStmt = DataManipulator.db.compileStatement(INSERT2);
}
```

---

Alternatively, you should consider creating two different handler classes, one for each table.

Comment: HI Sam, i tried using a 2nd method called "datamanipulator2" however when i called it from "appointment" java class it pointed to the 1st "dm" and did not recognize the 2nd...probably because the public class is just "datamanipulator", I'm new to this so, im trying to understand the best way/approach. Thx!

Comment: I mean, not sure how to do it.